# Does the iPhone support cookies when a webpage is opened in fullscreen mode?

Tags: mobile-safari, iphone, iphone-standalone-web-app

I can't find this information anywhere. Does the iPhone allow cookies to be stored when a webpage is opened in full screen mode (by placing a link on the home screen)?

Answer (score 4):

I've experienced the iPhone not storing cookies when using fullscreen mode (added to homescreen). Not sure why, it did work if I just ran it in Safari as usual.

Ended up using localStorage. It's actually less hassle to implement so no reason to not use it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine so - but you can also use localStorage too:

```
localStorage["key"] = "value"
```

Answer (score 0):

The full-screen mode is still safari running with the UI hidden (if set so). So, there is no reason for cookies to be disabled in this mode.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Characteristics/Characteristics.html

> Safari on iOS supports cookies. Use of
>   cookies can streamline user
>   interaction with web content by saving
>   the user’s context, preferences, and
>   previously entered data.
>
> ...
>
> Safari on iOS allows web apps to run
>   in full-screen mode. Web apps that
>   launch from a web clip icon on the
>   user’s Home screen can hide the UI for
>   Safari on iOS, so that they look more
>   like native applications.